# Convert API call from http to https in JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I'm pulling images from an API that uses an image from an insecure location (http).  In order to properly serve it on my app, I need it to be via https.  Is there any way to convert it prior to being served on the page?

Here's what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   console.log("ready!");

var url = 'https://api.petfinder.com/pet.getRandom';

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    jsonp: "callback",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {
        key: "4a9698752f4139c768c657d4776e1fbf",
        animal: 'dog',
        output: 'basic',
        format: 'json'
    },
    // Here is where we handle the response we got back from Petfinder
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response); // debugging

        var dogName = response.petfinder.pet.name.$t;
        var img = response.petfinder.pet.media.photos.photo[2].$t;
        var id = response.petfinder.pet.id.$t;

        var newName = document.createElement('a');
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newName.textContent = dogName;
        newName.href = 'https://www.petfinder.com/petdetail/' + id;

        var newImg = document.createElement('img');
        newImg.src = img;

        var list = document.createElement("div");
        list.setAttribute("id", "List");
        document.body.appendChild(list);

        newDiv.appendChild(newName);
        list.appendChild(newDiv);
        list.appendChild(newImg);
    }
  })
})
```

My thought is to encode the object property via a variable then somehow convert that variable, but I don't know how to do it.  I don't think I'm googling the right question because this doesn't seem like it would be that hard.

```
var encodedUrl = encodeURIComponent(img);
        console.log(encodedUrl);
```

Comment: You cannot make a remote resource HTTPS if it is not served as HTTPS.

Comment: The URL you currently use (https://api.petfinder.com/pet.getRandom) is served as HTTPS, so what is not working?

Comment: It's the image.  

    var img = response.petfinder.pet.media.photos.photo[2].$t;

Comment: And what is the URL of the image. Please post it. If that resource is not available as HTTPS you cannot "convert" it to HHTPS.

Comment: So I think the answer is no, but here's the URL that is generated by that var (technically, it's a random generation, but here's the most recent)

http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/39884713/1/?bust=1511126338&width=500&-x.jpg

Comment: Can use a proxy on your server to retrieve image and serve on https